# Compare values in Dictionary with Another List Items

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, compare

I have a problem here. I have implemented a dictionary MASTERDATALIST and a list DEPARTMENTLIST containing s specific set of items.

What I need is to compare the values of each key in MASTERDATALIST with the items of DEPARTMENTLIST.

If they are not equal, then that key should be added to another list "FAILEDLIST"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Scaning the list and seeking the dictionary comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you mean by `If they are not equal` is `If the key is not found in the list`.

What you need to do is:

- loop through the items in MasterDataList
- loop through the values for each item in the dictionary
- check if DepartmentList contains this item
- if not, add the item to FailedList

  ```
      MasterDataList.Add("key1", new List<string>() { "list1_item1", "list1_item2" });
      MasterDataList.Add("key2", new List<string>() { "list2_item1", "list2_item2" });
      MasterDataList.Add("key3", new List<string>() { "list3_item1", "list3_item2" });

      DepartmentList.Add("list1_item1");
      DepartmentList.Add("list1_item2");
      DepartmentList.Add("list2_item1");
      DepartmentList.Add("list2_item2");

      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in MasterDataList)
      {
          foreach (var listItem in item.Value)
          {
              if (!DepartmentList.Contains(listItem))
                  FailedList.Add(listItem);
          }

      }

      foreach (var item in FailedList)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
  ```

Comment: I am sorry I wasnt clear with my query. My problem is a bit different Dictionary<string , List<string>> MatsrDataList = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();           for each key there will be a list of values and i have to check whether all values are same as department list items

Comment: You can loop again through the list for each key in your dictionary and check whether that item in the list exists on the other list. Please see edited answer.